# http request from node.js local server port 5000 to 8000 gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I am trying to make a GET request from localhost:8000 to localhost:5000 for the url '/serverTest'. I get socket hang up error. How do I fix this?

Server on port 5000 (server which will process the request):

```
var express = require("express"), http = require('http');
app.get('/serverTest', function(req, res){
    //authenticate request
    //send message
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify({message:'hello'}));
}); 
app.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Server on port 8000 (server which makes the request):

```
var express = require("express"), http = require('http');
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
    makeACall();
});


function makeACall(){
    var options = {
        host:'localhost',
        port: 5000,
        path: '/serverTest',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(response) {
        var str = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);
        });
    });
}
```

Error obtained by the server hosted at port 8000:

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1442:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1538:23)
at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:910:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), you have to at some point call [`request.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding) to actually send the request.

> Note that in the example `req.end()` was called. With `http.request()` one must always call `req.end()` to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

```
http.request(options, function(response) {
    // ...
}).end();
```

Or, with `GET` requests, you can also use [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) which will call `request.end()`.

```
http.get(options, function(response) {
    // ...
});
```